# How to customized the Materializecss Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I need to change the tooltip background color and instead of "hover" like to make it as the "click" event.
HTML code:

```
    <a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Need to customize this tooltip">Hover me!</a>
```

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ujbv2yz/2/

Answer (score 0):

You customize the style by overriding these CSS classes..

```
.material-tooltip > .backdrop {
    ...
}

.material-tooltip > span {
    ...
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/jmsRHCcLar

I don't know of a way to activate it on click instead of hover.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the CSS related files to a selector called "backdrop".

```css
.backdrop
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    visibility: hidden;

    width: 14px;
    height: 7px;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 0;

    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    background-color: #323232;
}
```

Its located on the css folder of the framework.

Comment: This fix is still available.